# pass string from startActivityForResult to onActivityResult in RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, android-intent

I want to upload image and pass string(UID) from `startActivityForResult` to `onActivityResult`, and get the string(UID) on `onActivityResult`.

The `startActivityForResult` in `RecyclerView` and `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity`.

I can upload image but can't get the string(UID), the string(UID) is `null` on `onActivityResult`.

[The Null Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcZG9.jpg)

I would appreciate if someone can help me with my questions.

Here is `startActivityForResult` in `RecyclerView`:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private Button UploadImageButton;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            UploadImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.UploadImageButton);

            UploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                    intent.putExtra("UID", textView.getText().toString());

                    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 6);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity`:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (resultData != null) {
                String UID = resultData.getStringExtra("UID");
                Log.d("UID", UID);
            }
        }
    }
```

[The layout placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/042k3.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Note**
Your startActivityForResult() will only give result of the selected image in the form of Uri. Which means, whatever extras you sent via the intent is useless.

So to solve your issue, one thing you can do is first get the result of the startActivityForResult(), i.e. image Uri, then combine that with the "UID" and then pass these to he MainActivity.